# what is the accuracy of plotting lat/long positions on a map?

Tags: geolocation, maps, geocoding

I'm working on a project where I need to plot points/icons indicating the location of ships. I receive this data periodically.

Since all the points are located in the sea, I do not need to geocode an address. I just need to show the points on an interactive map.

Are there any free standalone tools that allow plotting points on an interactive map?

EDIT:

I'm refering at something like [this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/VectorLayers.ipynb) example:

Where I have a set of coorditanes I receive from an external service:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[35.67, 139.78], zoom_start=13)

locations = [
    [35.6762, 139.7795],
    [35.6718, 139.7831],
    [35.6767, 139.7868],
    [35.6795, 139.7824],
    [35.6787, 139.7791]
]
```

From there I can either plot the dots or create a polygon:

[image]

For this particular case the library folium was used.

My concern is regarding the precision of the plot and the libraries used in the back for the calculation:

Does this libraries use just a mathematical function to plot the points on the math or is a externat geocoding library like google maps or argis used for this? I guees not since I´m not looking for addresses but rather to plot the dots.

And which degree of error can I expect to get from this plots?

Comment: You should elaborate more on what type of input data you're working with.

Comment: @user3474985 I added more details to the question

Comment: Okay, I think you may need to re-write the question because it sounds like you already know the answer to the question of whether or not a geocoding tool is needed in your case i.e. it's not, because you don't need to translate an address into lat/long coordinates - you already have this information. If you're asking what the accuracy of plotting lat/long positions on a map is then that is mainly dependent on the accuracy of your input data, not the mapping libraries. Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Comment: @user3474985 You are rigth, I just edited the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, regarding the existence of **free standalone tools**. The answer depends on what you mean by "free" and if you are looking for

1. a ready-made app, or
2. library you would use as a basis for building your own tool.

For 1., there are plenty of pages where you can simply import coordinates and see the result on a map, including, but not limited to:

- http://geojson.io/
- http://kepler.gl/demo
- [Google map](https://www.google.com/maps), [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) (just type the coordinates into the search box like 12.1234,56.3454)
- http://www.hamstermap.com/quickmap.php (also an example of what happens if you deploy a map service using Google Maps thinking that it's free)

For 2., practically all map providers have APIs (for multiple programming languages & environments) through which you can draw points and polygons on maps. They also have rather comprehensive collections of examples:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-markers/
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/
- https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html?q=geojson
- https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/

Regarding "free", this is where it gets tricky. You can use the maps for personal development purposes and certain types of public websites & demos for free, but as soon as you start using them for commercial purposes, even internally in your company, they are actually not free at all but cost something like $10k/year (see, e.g., [Google Maps pricing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/) and be sure to read all the small print). Even though OpenStreetMap map material is free, there are no free and high-quality services ("tile providers") that you can rely on as a map backend in your own apps.

Regarding **accuracy**, the formulas used by these libraries have at least meter-level accuracy so everything should definitely be accurate enough for ships. The accuracy of the maps themselves is also meter-level. For example, it is not uncommon for outlines of buildings to be off by a few meters if you compare maps from different providers.

However, if you have maps of *China*, then you have to be careful with the [GCJ coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_geographic_data_in_China). Some of the maps are in WGS and some in GCJ and the difference can be hundreds of meters.